# Update rows in mysql from one table to another

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to run a query that updates rows from one table to another. I want to take the values from shopping_cat_id and put them into existing rows in the table merchants where the ids match.

here is my query thats giving me error 1064..

```
UPDATE `merchants` SET `category_id`=[shopping_cat_id] WHERE merchants.id = shopping.shopping_id


(SELECT shopping_id, shopping_cat_id FROM shopping)
```

Comment: Does that query really look valid to you? Does `[shopping_cat_id]` seem like it is correct?

Comment: Should it be shopping.shopping_cat_id ? I tried that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE merchants m 
    inner join shopping s on 
               m.id = s.shopping_id
   SET m.category_id=s.shopping_cat_id
```

It should have some where clause of course. Unless you want to update all.

Comment: Try it now... took out the `

Comment: I got it, i changed the merchants.id to m.id….  Thanks, I'll accept this.